# How to URL Encode a string in SharePoint Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I am working on a SharePoint 2010 workflow in SharePoint Designer.  I'd like to send an email where the body contains a custom URL that would go somewhere outside SharePoint.

I'd like to include some parameters such as "Title" from my list, but I recognize that people may enter a Title that includes special characters such as "&" or "?" and I don't want the value to "break" the URL.

In code elsewhere I would URLEncode that string holding the Title, to be sure it wouldn't break my URL.  But I can't find a way to do this in the workflow.

I'd also be willing to do a find/replace on some common ones, to manually remove the "&", but I don't see a string replace either.

Is this functionality not available outside of building something custom?  Or do I just not see it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: In Send Email action... In body section you can add hyperlinks. Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: SP 2013 workflow has string operation actions. Not sure about SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to encode a string to build a URL, then you can use the BuildUri activity and set all your queries in the Query field.